# C# Equivalent of VB 6 DoEvents

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vb6

VB6 had a DoEvents() method that you called to return control to the OS and mimic multi-threaded behavior in that single threaded environment.

What is the .NET framework equivalent of VB 6 DoEvents()?

Comment: I think you are thinking of Doevents.  Yield is a .NET method used in enumeration handling.  And the equivalent in .NET is Application.DoEvents() (regardless of language used)

Comment: `Application.DoEvents() == DoEvents`?

Comment: @Marlon: I see. Actually I recall asking this question every few years. I can't remember when I asked it last. You could be right and that could be the answer but my memory fails me. I am also thinking that I found a substitute in one of the methods of the System.Diagnostics.Process class but I can't remember for sure.

Comment: @Marlon: I checked the documentation. That Application class is in the System.Windows.Forms assembly. I assume it is the application (MFC WinApp class or a logical structure/class that controls the creation of the main window, registering it and the dispatching of messages to the WndProc). I am using a Console App. I could reference the System.Windows.Forms dll but that'll be a huge memory burden and I am still not sure if it'll work. I think I'll look into the Process class members.

Comment: Just to be clear before folks try and close this again `DoEvents()` !== `yield`. Thank you.

Comment: Before you embark on this path, read this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/is-doevents-evil.html. I've seen some horrible UI issues with DoEvents misuse, both in VB6 and .Net.

Comment: Call await Task.Delay(10); . It will give the Dispatcher 10 milliseconds to do other UI work. Works a treat.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Application.DoEvents() (part of WinForms)

Comment: What about WPF? I hate WinForms

Comment: @ColeJohnson The old Application.DoEvents() method has been depricated in WPF in favor of using a [*Dispatcher*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx) or a [*Background Worker Thread*](http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/03/wpf-multithreading-using-the-backgroundworker-and-reporting-the-progress-to-the-ui/) to do the processing as you have described. See the links for a couple of articles on how to use both objects.

Comment: Generally, I don't recommend using DoEvents anyways. It can halt a GUI. Google problems of Application.DoEvents

Comment: The existence of Application.DoEvents() is for the migration of VB6 programs. Newly developed programs should not use this approach.

Comment: Dispatcher.Yield is much better than Application.DoEvents

Comment: Still works in 2020 when needed in a pinch for a quick and dirty Winforms protoype.

Answer (score 25):

you can use `Application.DoEvents()`. Why not use **[Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)** class or simply **[Background Workers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)**? If you are doing in .net environment, don't use `DoEvents`. Leave it on VB6.

Comment: You've totally missed the point of the thread. Putting work on a background thread is for separating UI work from background work. This isn't the problem. The problem is how to "return control to the OS and mimic multi-threaded behavior in that single threaded environment". UI can lock up the screen, but you cannot put UI work on a background thread or you will get a cross thread exception. The answer is to use await Dispatcher.Yield() inside the loop of heavy work.

Comment: Because it was specifically asked for, less complicated and does what is needed.

Answer (score 5):

The following is a general DoEvents type method

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace Utilites
{
/// <summary>
/// Emulates the VB6 DoEvents to refresh a window during long running events
/// </summary>
public class ScreenEvents
{
    [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
    public static void DoEvents()
    {
        DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
            new DispatcherOperationCallback(ExitFrame), frame);
        Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
    }

    public static object ExitFrame(object f)
    {
        ((DispatcherFrame)f).Continue = false;

        return null;
    }
}
}
```

It doesn't need to know about the application.

Answer (score 1):

If you call Application.DoEvents() in your code, your application can handle the other events. For example, if you have a form that adds data to a ListBox and add DoEvents to your code, your form repaints when another window is dragged over it. If you remove DoEvents from your code, your form will not repaint until the click event handler of the button is finished executing. For more information on messaging, see User Input in Windows Forms.

Unlike Visual Basic 6.0, the DoEvents method does not call the Thread.Sleep method.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use Application.DoEvents(). It will have reentrancy issues. You should call inside the loop:

```
await System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Yield()
```

It will do the same thing. You will need to put it in a async method though. This has the added advantage of marking the method as asynchronous for calling methods. It's nice to suffix methods that call await Dispatcher.Yield with Async(). The method is not naturally async (i.e. it does have CPU bound work) but for all intents and purposes the method becomes async as it will not lock up the calling thread.